# Why $\overline{z}$ is not differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

1. By definition the derivative of $\overline{z}$ is:

\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\overline{z+\Delta h}-\overline{z}}{\Delta h}&=\lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\overline{z}+\overline{\Delta h}-\overline{z}}{\Delta h}
\\&=\lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\overline{\Delta h}}{\Delta h}
\\&=\lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{{\Delta x-i\Delta y}}{\Delta x+i\Delta y}
\\&=\lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{r(\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha)}{r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)}
\\&=\lim_{\Delta h\to 0}\frac{\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha}
\end{align}

How should it be continue with turning over to $\frac{e^{-i\alpha}}{e^{i\alpha}}$?

2. Is there an intuitive explanation why the conjugate function is not differentiable? As it is just "reflection" on $x$- axis

Comment: Yes. Continue in exponential form. You will see that the limit depends on $\alpha$. This is not okay for computing the derivative, because it should be independent of how exactly you approached the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, a function $f$ of one variable is differentiable at a point $p$ if for some tiny region $U$ around $p$, applying $f$ looks like multiplying by some number / scalar (in other words, scaling and rotating), relative to $p$ and $f(p)$. No matter how you scale and rotate, you can never flip. Thus complex conjugation doesn't look like scalar multiplication locally, and therefore is not differentiable.

Comment: in the one real variable case I know that differentiable means that there is no "point peaks" like in $|x|$ therefore $f(x)=|x|$ is flipping and vice versa?

Comment: Very nice explanation. @gbox A derivative is a *linear approximation*, and linear means multiplying by a number. In $\Bbb R$ multiplication is just stretching (factor $>1$), shrinking (factor in $(0,1)$) or mirroring (factor $<0$). But looking at this from $\Bbb C$, this mirroring is just a $180^°$ rotation instead. Actually multiplication in $\Bbb C$ is just rotations and scaling, no mirroring involved. So a derivative here does just not *provide* this transformation that $\bar z$ applies, namely mirroring.

Comment: @gbox For a point peak on a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, on a small neighbourhood around that peak, the function looks like it's folding the number line in half. No multiplication does that. For a differentiable peak, on the other hand, it looks like multiplication by $0$. This is exactly what allows the graph to change cardinal direction while still being differentiable: It slows down to a stop first.

Comment: very very useful comment.

Answer (score 4):

This will not expand on your limit proof in your question. But there is this nice theorem in complex analysis, called the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem):

> **Theorem.** Given two complex differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ and a set $D$ with some limit point (e.g. an open set, a line, ...). If $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in D$ then we already have $f=g$.

Your function $f(z)=z$ and its conjugate $\bar f$ agree on the real line, i.e. $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$. The real line is a set with limit point, so when both functions are complex differentiable, then $z=\bar z$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$. Obviously wrong. But because we know that $z$ is complex differentiable, $\bar z$ can not.

This works for all non-constant functions $f$ for which the restriction to $\Bbb R $ is real, i.e. $f|_\Bbb R:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. For example, this shows that $\overline\sin (z)$ is *not* complex differentiable.

Comment: How does this theorem called?

Comment: @gbox It is called the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem). I will include this in my answer. Note that the statement on wikipedia is a bit weaker as it only allowes $D$ to be an open set.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that by approaching to the origin first on the real axis and second on the complex axis, that means: Consider for the first limit $\Delta x=0$ and for the second limit consider $\Delta y=0$. You get two different limits, and therefore the limit does not exist. Hence $f(z)=\overline{z}$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Conjugation is real-differentiable, in the sense that all partial derivatives of it exist everywhere. However, this does not mean it's complex differentiable. A real differentiable function $x+yi\mapsto u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is complex differentiable provided that
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\end{align}$$
These are the Cauhcy-Riemann eComplex conjugation does not satisfy this, since $u(x,y)=x, v(x,y)=-y$.

Intuitively, $z\mapsto \overline z$ is not differentiable since its directional derivatives are different depending on their direction, as opposed to a function like $z^2$.